# rails save dangerous attribute srror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refinerycms

I'm getting the following error

i created a new scaffold bid with few fields

when i tried to access localhost:3000/bids/new

i get following error

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in BidsController#new

save is defined by ActiveRecord
```

in server side i see this result:

```
Started GET "/bids/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-07 12:52:43 +0530
Processing by BidsController#new as HTML
Refinery::Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
Refinery::User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 779ms

ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError (save is defined by ActiveRecord):
  app/controllers/bids_controller.rb:27:in `new'
  app/controllers/bids_controller.rb:27:in `new'
```

what am i missing or is refinerycms mounted at / is overriding functions?

please help me

Comment: can I see the attributes, you have defined in Bid Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems, you have defined some reserved ActiveRecord's attributes, If you did so, than you either have to change those or try something else. Just add a gem in your gemfile and the gem will take care of name collisions automatically.

```
gem 'safe_attributes'
```

hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, i changed the field name from save to save_x that i created, and now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem,

The problem is not with refinery cms

i created a field with name save:boolean

i changed it to save_x:boolean and now it works fine